# Send Email from Feedback form WebPage using JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to send email from asp.net vb.net webpage. Everything works fine with localhost but when it is deployed to server it won't work. so if JavaScript would do this job, can anyone provide me the javascript code to put it in html page or any altranatives.

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


Try
    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New  _
Net.NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password")
    SmtpServer.Port = 587
    SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    mail = New MailMessage()
    mail.From = New MailAddress("YOURusername@gmail.com")
    mail.To.Add("TOADDRESS")
    mail.Subject = "Test Mail"
    mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL"
    SmtpServer.Send(mail)
    MsgBox("mail send")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try



End Sub
```

Comment: Another alternative would be showing your code that work on localhost but fails on remote server for us to see and identify what's wrong..

Comment: Much better to work on your server side issues.  Javascript will not really help you here. At best you will get limited functionality using `mailto:`

Comment: @wooer Uploaded the code

Comment: @Jon P  mailto: only works if there is external email client. but can't be used for feedback form.

Comment: Exactly my point with the limitations of javascript. And how does the code not work on the production server? What errors are thrown?

Comment: @JonP i doesn't throw any error. It just does not work. I believe Server side code won't work for this. as far as i know.

Comment: Your `try ... catch...`  block is swallowing the exception. You will never see `MsgBox` as this will execute on the server, not the web browser. Server side code will work you just need to be able to debug it properly.

Comment: Replace `MsgBox(ex.ToString)` with `Response.Write("<!--Error: " + ex.Message + " -->")` then *view source* on the web page to see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this helper. set configuration like this. try with EnableSsl = true.

https://musthaan.wordpress.com/2013/10/02/sent-e-mail-from-asp-net-site-using-gmails-smtp-server/

Comment: Musthaan is correct - you must use ssl for sending emails from gmail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in a javascript block to launch the default emailer application of the client-side system. The first line is a regular expression to strip the text of " "(spaces) and replace them with "%20" as it is the equivalent text for space while launching Outlook. If you don't make this change, the body of the email client will have the text "UNDEFINED".

```
var body = emailBody.replace(/\s/g,"%20")
document.location = "mailto:"+email+"?subject="+subject+"&body="+emailBody;
```